# Product tags in infusionsoft

Tags: infusionsoft

I need to tag products that are downloadable in Infusionsoft. I will be uploading those products through API. Is there a way i can achieve this? I can tag contacts but not products? Also an alternative was to use custom fields but they are also only for Contact Service,Company and order.

Comment: can i ask what you're trying to achieve? You cannot tag products, but perhaps there's another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create tags for anything other than contacts.

There are a few ways to hack it though:

- Append a specific value to the SKU
- Use the NeedsDigitalDelivery column
- Set a specific value in the InventoryLimit column

These options may not be ideal, but they may provide a workaround to the limitations of the product table.